# Cannot use Retroarch on 15.04, GUI seems unresponsive to mouse

Tags: 15.04, gui, emulation

I [installed](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/05/install-retroarch-ubuntu-1504-1404/) retroarch:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/stable      
sudo apt-get update      
sudo apt-get install retroarch retroarch-* libretro-*
```

There didn't seem to be any errors with the installation.

However I can't seem to interact with the GUI with a mouse. I can scroll through options on a keyboard but cannot select anything.

I followed these [troubleshooting instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RetroArch#Input_devices_do_not_operate):

> Is is solved by manually adding a rule in
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/99-evdev.rules, with KERNEL=="event*",
>   NAME="input/%k", MODE="666" as its contents. Reload udev rules by
>   running:

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules
```

> If rebooting the system or replugging the devices are not options,
>   permissions may be forced using:

```
# chmod 666 /dev/input/event*
```

I'm not sure what the next step is, how do I get this software working?

Update: I can use my [Play Sega](http://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-PLAY-SEGA-Game-Controller/dp/B00HZJHR32/) controller with it OK. Is this functionality by design then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

retroarch defaults toto keyboard. Use z and x to select options and arrows to navigate up and down. Use arrows to scroll down to settings. Press X. Scroll down to Menu and press X. then scroll down to mouse support and press X to turn on the mouse.
Don't forget to save your configuration

Hope this helps